# Retaining special character while reading from html java?

Tags: java, html, unicode, jsoup

i am trying to read html source file which contains German characters like ä ö ü ß €

Reading using JSOUP

```
citAttr.nextElementSibling().text()
```

Encoding the string with

```
unicodeEscaper.translate(citAttr.nextElementSibling().text())
```

**org.apache.commons.lang3.text.translate.UnicodeEscaper**

Issue is after reading the charecters turns into �

But where as reading CSV with Encoded type UTF-8 with above unicodeEscaper saving & retriving the charecters works fine.

```
unicodeEscaper.translate(record.get(headerPosition.get(0)))
```

Whats the issue with reading from html ?? did try with StringUtilEscaper methods still the charecters turns into �

```
private String getText(Part p) throws MessagingException, IOException {
    if (p.isMimeType("text/*")) {
        String s = (String) p.getContent();
        textIsHtml = p.isMimeType("text/html");
        return s;
    }
```

This is how i am reading email which have html content!

Comment: What is the encoding of the HTML file?

Comment: @AlexRudenko <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"

Answer (score 1):

I just answered a similar question today...  I guess I can just type what I know about extended character sets (foreign-language characters), since that's one of the major facets of the software I write.

- Java's internal **`String's`** all use **`16-bit chars`** (The primitive type **`char`** is a 16-bit primitive value.  The name **`UTF-8`** is a little misleading since it is used to represent the 16-bit "Unicode Space" (using two 8-bit numbers).  This means that Java (and Java **`String's`**) ***have no problems representing the entire Unicode foreign-language alphabet ranges.***
- JSoup, and just about any HTML tool written in Java, when asking for website pages to download, will return 16-bit characters - as Java **`String's`** - just fine, without any problems!  If there are problems viewing these ranges, it is likely not the download process, nor a JSoup or `HttpUrlConnection` setting.  When you save a web-page to a String in Java, you haven't lost those characters, you essentially get **`UTF-8`** "for free."
- **HOWEVER:** Whenever a programmer attempts to save a **`UTF-8 String`** to a **`'.txt' File`** or a **`'.html' File`**, if you then go on to view that content (that file) in a web-browser, all you might see is that annoying question mark: �.  This is because you need to make sure to let your web-browser know that the **`'.html' File`** that you have saved using Java - *is not intended to be interpreted using the (much older, much shorter) **`8-bit ASCII`** Range.*

If you view an **`'.html' File`** in any web-browser, or upload that file to Google Cloud Platform (or some hosting site), you must do one of two things:

> - Include the **`<META> Tag`** mentioned in the comments: **`<meta charset="UTF-8">`**  in the HTML Page's `<HEAD> ... </HEAD>` section.
> - Or provide the setting in whatever hosting platform you have to identify the file as `'text/html, charset=UTF-8'`.  In Google Cloud Platform Storage Buckets there is a popup menu to assign this setting to any file.

Comment: here i am not downloading or viewing the content in HTML, all i am doing is reading content as java string then parsing and converting to unicode then save that's it.

Comment: I tried to say that the statement "Save as a Java `String` and convert it to `Unicode`" doesn't have any meaning (to me, and I am pretty sure I understand this stuff very well, but I do make mistakes)...   In Java - _`String's` already are in Unicode._  This is because Unicode `char's` are 16-bits and Java `String's` are comprised of 16-bit `char's` - so they are ***already*** Unicode `char's` (not `ASCII char's` - which are 8-bits).  If you will answer the question: "How are you "viewing" these files?  And where are you saving them?"  Maybe I could help you more...

Comment: My coding (for going on 4 years now), has been language translation - _although I have digressed into HTML parsing_... so I have been buried in foreign-language characters (UNICODE) in Java and text-files / html-files very often!!

Comment: @I am saving that data into DB(mysql) and retrieving back displaying in primefaces page .xhtml

Comment: OK... Well... Let me say two things:  ① I don't do databases much and ② I can make a suggestion, which you really ought to check (even if i'm wrong)...    There are two 'things' or 'configurations' I would _really strong suggest checking_...

Comment: ①Does the **`MySQL DB`** have a configuration to ensure that 16-bit (UNICODE) characters are being saved into the database?  Can you look at your table-rows and see the **`ä ö ü ß €`** German charactes?  ② (More Importantly, more likely...) The **`'.xhtml' Files`** that are being produced must have either a **`<META CHARSET='UTF-8'>`** Meta-Tag in their **`<HEAD>...</HEAD>`** section, or the Web-Server that is serving these pages must indicate that their **`CONTENT-TYPE`** is set to **`UTF-8`**