# Jsoup connect(url) get encoding

Tags: java, jsoup

I'm having some issues when connecting to a URL with Jsoup, I am unable to set the encoding of HTML, the text in the tags are only displayed as "?". I've searched exhaustedly here in the forum and in the documentation but I can't make any solution that is proposed to work.

This is one of the HTML parts that gives me the issue when running the Jsoup connect

[image: Accent issue]

The result when running the connection is this:

[image: Printed HTML]
<sub>(source: [i.ibb.co](https://i.ibb.co/kKkw53w/Capture2.jpg))</sub>

If I try to use the parser, I have the following message: "Please enable JavaScript to view the page content"

As described in some threads here in stackoverflow, I've changed the output encoding to check if the problem was that, but the result was the same. I tried saving the content to a file in the correct iso and it didn't work as well, same output with the question marks.

The snippet that I am using is yet very simple since I am just trying to get the HTML:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(a)
        .header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
        .postDataCharset("ISO-8859-1") // tried other encodings but no success as well, same output
        .get();

System.out.println(doc);
```

Have anyone had this problem before using the **connect().get()** from Jsoup?

### Update

Using another site the issue is not presented:

```
String a = "https://flatschart.com/html5/descricao.html";
        
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(a)
        .header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
        .postDataCharset("ISO-8859-1")
        .get();
        
System.out.println(doc);
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Here is one of my answers about this topic.  [UTF-8 Meta Tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64034234/retaining-special-character-while-reading-from-html-java/64035247#64035247).  Before going off the rails about what **Java** or **JSoup** is doing incorrectly, I would ask of you what editor or browser you are using to View the File that you have downloaded from your web-site using **JSoup**.  Java can handle 16-bit **UNICODE** easily - _by automatic_.

Comment: However, if you save the downloaded `String` to an **`'.html' File`**, and open that **`'.html' File`** in a browser, (usually) ***then and only then*** will you see the dreaded �.

Comment: Regarding the first question, I tried all browsers, iexplore, firefox and chrome, all had the text displayed correctly in the source code. Another attempt that I did was with another site with the same special accents, in there I didn't have the issue. I edited the post with this attempt.

Comment: ***Well, that's always the issue.***  I have been dealing with **UTF-8** foreign language characters going on 4 years now (in **Java**).  Java does **UTF-8** (again) "by automatic".  Two Points... **POINT 1:**  If you view your page in a browser - and the '�' is displayed - ***NEXT TIME*** try loading your file into a simple `Notepad`, and view whether or not the appropriiate characters are rendering.  **POINT 2:**  Include this in your `.html File` headers (the `<HEAD>...</HEAD>` part of your page) ... **`<META CHARSET=''UTF-8'>`**